# Expected identifier or "("

Tags: objective-c

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{           
    CLLocationManager *_locationManager;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *locationUpdatesSwitch;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *locationInformationLabel;

- (IBAction)toggleLocationUpdates:(id)sender;
{ //EXPECTED IDENTIFIER OR "(" 
    if (self.locationUpdatesSwitch.on == YES)

{
    if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] == NO)
    {
        UIAlertView *locationServicesDisabledAlert =
        [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location Services Disabled"
                                   message:@"This feature requires location services. Enable it in the privacy settingson your device"
                                  delegate:nil
                         cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [locationServicesDisabledAlert show];
        self.locationUpdatesSwitch.on = NO;
        return;
        ￼}
}

    else

    {
    // Switch was turned Off
}
}
```

Trying to work on a small core location based xcode project. could anyone help me out here? i dont see what i'm missing, but i get a "Expected identifier or "(" " error right after 
- (IBAction)toggleLocationUpdates:(id)sender;

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't write function bodies in the `@interface` part. Move them to the `.m` file, in `@implementation`.

Comment: Technically you should be able to write functions in headers. But I think the semicolon is the issue in this case.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Tom's answer You need to remove `;` of your ibaction method in your.m file

change

`- (IBAction)toggleLocationUpdates:(id)sender;`

to

`- (IBAction)toggleLocationUpdates:(id)sender {}`